# MVC2 page not being update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In my page (which displays a list of information), I call a webapage that gets user information and then calls a webservice and a a stored proc for a database on a page (the stored proc inputs or updates a row of data in the db).  WHen I click submit, the page is supposed to completely reload the first page with the new updated data and display it to the user.  Well, the data does submit to the db, and service, but my page reloads with the old information for some reason, even though I make a call to the entire action that generated the first page.  If I navigate back to the home page and then go to the page in question, the data does appear.  Should I be waiting or something to call this action again or something?

I do in fact have

```
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
```

attribute peppered on my actions and in my web.config.  Am I missing something?  Are there any catches places where I should be carefull when doing this?
I actually recall the entire action that creates the first page.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the HTTP request in Fiddler to make sure that the updated page is really being returned (instead of a cached, out-of-date version)? Are you submitting the page with a normal "submit" button, AJAX, or something else? Do you have any caching components enabled in IIS that might be causing this?

Comment: That is a good idea.  I don't understand why it would do that instead of just call the page again.  I will check this out in fidler.

Comment: Fiddler will tell you if the problem is client- or server-side. If the latter, there are some other places to look to isolate the problem.

Comment: Just looking at fidler, it doesn't appear as though I am not calling my action a second time.  It just looks like I am browsing backwords... All though, I don't see that anywhere in fidler.  Why would that be?

Comment: I actually call the method in my controller that loads the page.  Is there a standard way to do this in mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work right now.

```
    Random number = number Random();
    RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { value1 = number.Next(0, 100)});
```

I will go with it for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning a view directly from the post it may be using the old data.  Try redirecting to the GET action to show the results.